# Add Array values to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I ran into a problem and I can't find the method to get over it. basically I need to make a mutable dictionary with some values. All values are dynamic and I get them from web service or from other variables.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setObject:comment.text forKey:@"Comment"];
    [dict setObject:name.text forKey:@"Name"];
    [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",isPublic] forKey:@"VisibleForAll"];
po dict
{
    Comment = "no comment";
    Name = "test";
    VisibleForAll = 1;
    -> carts
}
```

Furthermore I want to add the following tree to my dictionary but I can't figure how to do this.

I have the necessary items in 2 `NSArray` `artID` and `qty` but I don't know how to create the bottom part so I can add it to the `dict`.

```
Carts {
       Cart {   
             ArticleID : 22
             Quantity : 1
            }
       Cart {   
             ArticleID : 45
             Quantity : 3
            }
       ...
      }
```

I will add it with `[dict setObject:carts forKey:@"Cart"]` but I don't know how to add values in such a manner that I will make my `dictionary` on the form I presented you.

Also, don't forget that the numbers or `Carts` is flexible. I will get it from a `Product.count`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your both array `artID` and `qty` have value at the same index for create a dictionary you can try like this

```
NSMutableArray *carts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSInteger i=0; i<products.count; i++) {
    //If you have custom class `cart` than use that
    Cart *cart = [[Cart alloc] init];
    cart.ArticleID = [[products objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"pid"];
    cart.Quantity = [[products objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"qty"];

    //If you not have any custom class than use Dictionary
    NSMutableDictionary *cart = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [cart setObject:[[products objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"pid"] forKey:@"ArticleID"];
    [cart setObject:[[products objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"pid"] forKey:@"Quantity"];
}
```

Now add this `carts` array to `Dictionary` with key

```
[dict setObject:carts forKey:@"carts"];
```

Comment: Your answer was partially correct but it helped me reach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSArray *pid = [products valueForKey:@"pid" ];
    NSArray *qty = [products valueForKey:@"qty"];

    NSMutableArray *carts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:products.count];



    for(NSInteger i=0; i<products.count; i++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *cart = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSMutableDictionary *cartemp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        [cart setObject:[pid objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"ArticleId"];
        [cart setObject:[qty objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"Quantity"];
        [cartemp setObject:cart forKey:@"Cart"];
        [carts addObject:cartemp];
    }

    [dict setObject:carts forKey: @"Carts"];
```